# How do you calculate input in python without using two inputs in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I calculate `1+2+3+4+5` on Python 3?

```
n = int(input())
print(n)
```

The above code works in Python 2 however it doesn't work in Python 3.

```
Input

1+2+3+4+5
```

```
Output

15
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `ast.literal_eval` like this in Python 3:

```
from ast import literal_eval
n = input()
print(literal_eval(n))
```

Example:

```
1+2+3+4+5
15
```

The reason it works in Python 2 is because in Python `input` was the same as `eval` in Python 3, to have a regular input in Python 2 you have to use `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Python's **eval()** allows you to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input. This function can be handy when you're trying to dynamically evaluate Python expressions from any input that comes as a string or a compiled code object.

```
a = eval(input())
print(a)
```

Comment: Eval is bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice